# Whats wrong with my faces

Tags: svg

I have imported an svg file for the word media, however when I add faces to it, it also adds faces to the gaps in the letters "d" and a"". Why is this and how do I solve that ? Thank you.

Amit

Comment: Please add images and more detail on your situation so we can help you. Edit your post to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "why is this and how do i solve" without any image reference

Answer (score 3):

If you just select the whole mesh and press <kbd>F</kbd>, Blender won't be able to know what's supposed to be holes and what's not, and it will fill everything. So create some additional vertices and fill the faces one by one with some <kbd>F</kbd>, except what's supposed to be holes:

[image]